# Samba public share

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

I created a folder share in Samba following the settings below:

```
[Loja4]
path = mypath
read only = no
guest ok = yes
guest only = yes
```

The shared folder is visible on the machines I try to access, but I cannot access them due to a permission error.

The global settings of the smb.conf have not been changed and the folder belongs to user nobody (with write and read permissions).

Edit:

The logs in the `/var/logs/samba` folder return the following information:

```
[2020/04/19 13:57:19.872551, 0] ../source3/smbd/service.c:774(make_connection_snum)
canonicalize_connect_path failed for service Loja4, path /media/svr-backup/eaa0e745-1ac9-4ba7-9c1d-937146eaebe7/Loja4
```

Comment: The last version of Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Is "svr-backup" a user name?

Comment: Yes, it is my main user.

Comment: I managed to create a share with him, but I need access without password to that folder. Is there any way to do this using that user?

Comment: I replaced "force user = nobody" with "force user = svr-backup" and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
writable = yes
force user = nobody
```

Comment: Although force user = nobody will work since this is Xubuntu and not an Ubuntu server would it not make more sense to have the shared folder owned by hofmanng96 then have the force user = hofmanng96. Otherwise the Xubuntu user would not have write access to the files added by the samba client.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `"force user = nobody"` with `"force user = svr-backup"` and it worked perfectly.